# SWIG C++ List to Java

Tags: java, c++, list, typedef, swig

I am trying to use SWIG to wrap C++ where it defined a LIST of objects like this

```
    typedef std::list<Country> CountryList;
```

What exactly do I have to have in the interface file to accomodate for this?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1):

You <s>simply</s> need to add the following to your swig interface file:

```
%include "std_list.i"
%include "Country.h" /* or declaration of Country */
%template(Country_List) std::list<Country>;
```

EDIT: I did not know that swig does not provide a `std_list.i` for Java to wrap `std::list`. Looking at the one provided for `std::vector`, this can be adapted to `std::list`. Note that most functionality is not available, since you really want to use iterators to access list elements. Anyway, here it goes:

std_list.i

```
%include <std_common.i>

%{
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>
%}

namespace std {
    template<class T> class list {
      public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef const value_type& const_reference;
        list();
        list(size_type n);
        size_type size() const;
        %rename(isEmpty) empty;
        bool empty() const;
        void clear();
        const_reference back();
        %rename(add) push_back;
        void push_back(const value_type& x);
        void pop_back();
    };
}
```

Instead of wrapping `std::list<Country>`, you may instead want to *convert* this to a corresponding list in Java. For this, however, you need to write appropriate [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_typemaps).

Comment: The problem is that, I'm wrapping C++ to Java and as it turns out, for Java they don't have std_list library.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I just updated my answer. Depending on what you actually want to do with the list in Java, the above may not satisfy you. You can add element access as done in `std_vector.i`, but each access would need to traverse the list.

Comment: So if I want to create a list of strings, could I simply just add the above interface file and do `%template(String) std::list<String>;`? Or is there some C++ code I need to write to implement this addition?

Comment: @Evil: Yes, you can do that. You need to implement `String`, of course, or use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @m7thon oh...but where does SWIG get the implementation for the template class? (This is just out of curiousity)

Comment: You mean `String`? Well, you need to tell SWIG about it. Either `%include "String.h"` (or similar) for your own `String` class, or use `%include "std_string.i"` for SWIG support of `std::string`.

Comment: @m7thon I meant for all the methods above, like `void pop_back();`. Might be a silly question :)

Comment: SWIG does not use any method *implementations* at all, only *declarations*, to generate the wrapper code. The wrapper code of course does include the relevant definitions so that it can be compiled, e.g., `#include <list>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108830/discussion-between-evil-washing-machine-and-m7thon).

Answer (score 0):

`std_list` is not yet in the "Latest Release" (swig-3.0.12) available from the [Downloads](http://www.swig.org/download.html), but already in the [master branch on github](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/std_list.i). You can just download and use (`%include`) it.